# simplifying second derivative

Tags: calculus

I'm following a tutorial on curve sketching and I got stuck on simplifying the second derivative: f" = $\frac{-4(x^2-1)^2-4x(x^2-1)(-4x)}{(x^2-1)^4}$ The answer they got is f" = $\frac{12x^2+4}{(x^2-1)^3}$

I'm not sure how they are getting that answer. Can someone explain?

Comment: Factor out $x^2-1$ from the terms in the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

If you factor an $(x^2-1)$ from both numerator and denominator:
$$\frac{-4(x^2-1)^2-4x(x^2-1)(-4x)}{(x^2-1)^4}\frac{(x^2-1)}{(x^2-1)} = \frac{-4(x^2-1)^2-4x(x^2-1)(-4x)}{(x^2-1)}\frac{(x^2-1)}{(x^2-1)^4}$$
you'll see something on the lines of $-4(x^2-1)-4x(-4x)=12x^2+4$ on the numerator itself
$$\dots = \frac{-4(x^2-1)-4x(-4x)}{(x^2-1)^3}=\frac{12x^2+4}{(x^2-1)^3}$$
which is exactly what you're seeking for!

Comment: ok that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{(x^2-1)\left(-4(x^2-1)-4x(-4x)\right)}{(x^2-1)^1(x^2-1)^3}$$

1. Factor $(x^2-1)$
2. Cancel $(x^2-1)$ from numerator and denominator